# Billingsley Probability and Measure, Problem $5.9$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm working on problem $5.9$ in Billingsley's *Probability and Measure*. See [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mneyz.png). Billingsley says one can prove $5.9$ by checking $5.39$ for $f(x, y) = - x^\frac{1}{p}y^\frac{1}{q}$ where $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$. I'm unable to prove that $f_{11} f_{22} \geq f_{12}^2$. In fact, I think I have a counterexample. Has anyone encountered this problem and is able to help me? Thank you!

Comment: We recommend you use MathJax (see help center) to format equations on this site. Also, if you think you have a counterexample, you should include it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

We have to show that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the conditions of the previous problem. Note that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} (x, y) = - \frac{1}{p}(\frac{1}{p} - 1) x^{\frac{1}{p} - 2} y^\frac{1}{q},$ $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} (x, y) = - \frac{1}{p}\frac{1}{q} x^{\frac{1}{p} - 1} y^{\frac{1}{q} - 1}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} (x, y) = - \frac{1}{q}(\frac{1}{q} - 1)y^{\frac{1}{q} - 2} x^\frac{1}{p}.$ Now since $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1,$ it is enough to compare $x^{\frac{1}{p} - 2} y^\frac{1}{q} \times y^{\frac{1}{q} - 2} x^\frac{1}{p}$ with $(x^{\frac{1}{p} - 1} y^{\frac{1}{q} - 1})^2.$ Of course, these quantities are equal and the conclusion follows from the previous problem. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you!! Somewhere along in working out the proof, I forgot the y part of f_11 and the x part of f_22. Sigh, I figured I was doing something silly incorrectly. Thanks. :)